# Angular/RxJS - Only call AJAX requests once, else emit current value of Observable

Tags: ajax, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am trying to display to users a list of 'reports' they can add which requires a combination of multiple AJAX requests and observables -- one request to an api to find the 'applications' they can access, and then multiple requests to a defined endpoint for each application. Once this step has been completed, I never need to make the ajax requests again.

I have something working but I do not really understand it and I feel like there should be a much easier way to do this.

I have some working code right now, however, I find it overly complicated and hardly understand how I got it to work.

```
private _applications: ReplaySubject<Application>;
private _applicationReports: ReplaySubject<ApplicationReports>;

// Ajax request to fetch which applications user has access to
public fetchApplications(): Observable<Application[]> {
    return this._http.get('api/applications').pipe(
        map(http => {
            const applications = http['applications'] as Application[];
            applications.forEach(app => this._applications.next(app));
            this._applications.complete();
            return applications;
        })
    );
}

// Returns an observable that contains all the applications
// a user has access to
public getApplications(): Observable<Application> {
    if (!this._applications) {
        this._applications = new ReplaySubject();
        this.fetchApplications().subscribe();
    }
    return this._applications.asObservable();
}

// Returns an observable which shows all the reports a user has
// from all the application they can access
public getApplicationReports(): Observable<ApplicationReports> {
    if (!this._applicationReports) {
        this._applicationReports = new ReplaySubject();
        this.getApplications().pipe(
            mergeMap((app: Application) => {
                return this._http.get(url.resolve(app.Url, 'api/reports')).pipe(
                    map(http => {
                        const reports: Report[] = http['data'];

                        // double check reports is an array to avoid future errors
                        if (!reports || !Array.isArray(reports)) {
                            throw new Error(`${app.Name} did not return proper reports url format: ${http}`);
                        }
                        return [app, reports];
                    }),
                    catchError((err) => new Observable())
                );
            })
        ).subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
                const application: Application = data[0];
                const reports: Report[] = data[1];

                // need to normalize all report urls here
                reports.forEach(report => {
                    report.Url = url.resolve(application.Url, report.Url);
                });

                const applicationReports = new ApplicationReports();
                applicationReports.Application = application;
                applicationReports.Reports = reports;

                this._applicationReports.next(applicationReports);
            }
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }, () => {
            this._applicationReports.complete();
        });
    }
    return this._applicationReports.asObservable();
}
```

Expected functionality:

When a user opens the 'Add a report' component, the application starts a series of ajax calls to fetch all the applications the user has, and all the reports from those applications. Once all the ajax request are completed, the user sees a list of reports they can choose to add. If the user opens the 'Add a report' component a second time, they already have the report list and the application doesn't need to send more ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the overall architecture of your application. If you are a following a Redux-style architecture ([ngrx in Angular](https://ngrx.io)), then you can solve this problem by caching the API responses in the store, i.e., `LoadApplicationsAction => Store => Component(s)`.

In this flow, your requests to load the list of applications and the details for each only occur once.

If you are not implementing such an architecture, then the same principles still apply, but your constructs/implemenation changes. Per your code example, you're on the right track. You can either `shareReplay(1)` the response of `fetchApplications` that essentially replays the most recent value emitted by the source to future subscribers. Or similarly, you can store the results in a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) which achieves a similar result.

#### Suggestions

Regardless of whether you choose to implement ngrx or not, you can simplify your Rx code. If I understand your expected results, you are only trying to show the user a list of `Report` objects. If that is the case, you can do that like this (untested but should get you to the right result):

```
public fetchApplicationReports(): Observable<Report[]> {
  return this._http.get('api/application').pipe(
    mergeMap(apps => from(apps).pipe(
      mergeMap(app => this._http.get(url.resolve(app.Url, 'api/reports'))
    ),
    concatAll()
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple cache can be achieved with `shareReplay(1)` which uses a `ReplaySubject` internally.

If you want to get all your ApplicationReports in one array and don't need them to be emitted one after another you can use `forkJoin` to send multiple requests simultaneously.

The final code could look like this.

```ts
private applicationReportsCache$: Observable<ApplicationReports[]>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getAllApplicationReports(): Observable<ApplicationReports[]> {
  if (!this.applicationReportsCache$) {
    this.applicationReportsCache$ = this.requestAllApplicationReports().pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  return this.applicationReportsCache$;
}

private requestAllApplicationReports(): Observable<ApplicationReports[]> {
  return this.http.get('api/applications').pipe(
    map(http => http['applications'] as Application[]),
    mergeMap(apps =>
      forkJoin(apps.map(app =>
        this.http.get(url.resolve(app.Url, 'api/reports')).pipe(
          map(http => {
            const reports: Report[] = http['data'];
            // double check reports is an array to avoid future errors
            if (!reports || !Array.isArray(reports)) {
              throw new Error(`${app.Name} did not return proper reports url format: ${http}`);
            }
            // need to normalize all report urls here
            reports.forEach(report => {
              report.Url = url.resolve(application.Url, report.Url);
            });
            const applicationReports = new ApplicationReports();
            applicationReports.Application = app;
            applicationReports.Reports = reports;
            return applicationReports;
          }),
          catchError(err => of('ERROR'))
        )
      )))
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I understand better what is happening and definitely cleaned up a lot of code. It was difficult to understand how to continue the stream when any of the application reports ajax requests errored, however, the combo of catchError() and filter() solved the issue.

```
private _reports: Observable<Report[]>;
public getReports() {
    if (!this._reports) {
        this._reports = this.fetchApplications().pipe(
            mergeMap((applications) => from(applications).pipe(
                mergeMap((application) => this.fetchApplicationReports(application).pipe(
                    catchError(error => {
                        return of('error');
                    })
                )),
                filter(result => {
                    return result !== 'error';
                })
            )),
            toArray(),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }
    return this._reports;
}

private fetchApplications(): Observable<Application[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._gnetUtilsService.getGnetUrl('api/gnet/applications')).pipe(
        map(http => http['applications'] as Application[]
    );
}

private fetchApplicationReports(app: Application): Observable<Report[]> {
    return this._http.get(url.resolve(app.Url, 'api/reports')).pipe(
        map(http => http['data'] as Report[])
    );
}
```

Some things I learned:

- mergeMap() and from() with the fetchApplications() observable converts the Application[] into a stream of each application, so that I can call ajax requests for each application
- catchError() within the fetchApplicationReports() observables prevents the observable from ending, and the parent filter() simply ignores all unsuccessful requests
- toArray() combines all the emitted Report[] into one array
- storing the observable and using shareReplay(1) ensures any following subscriptions will just receive the first result without initiating the ajax requests over again

I think I could clean it up a little more, but as of now everything is working as I expect -- the first component calling getReports() initiates all the ajax requests, all the errored out requests are disposed of and never emitted, and all component afterwards get the final result without making more ajax requests.